# communicate between controllers in AngularJS typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, master-detail

I believe that the best way to communicate between controllers is to use a service to store a message.

I am currently building a master-detail application and would like to use a service to store the list item that has been clicked in the master so that I know which element to fetch in the detail.

So as I understand it the chain of events should be like this:

1. User clicks on button in the master view.
2. Service updates local variable with the button that was clicked. The service then uses $broadcast to broadcast to the detail that the variable was changed.
3. Detail has a $on that then reacts to the button being clicked.

Does this flow make sense?

And can someone point me to a tutorial on how to implement this in typescript?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah that sounds about right. What you also can do is just assign the service variable to both the master controller scope and the child scope

Comment: You mean inject the service into both controllers? Which is what I had done. However I need the detail variable to update when the button is changed which is why I believe the best thing to do is a $broadcast on change in the service and have a $on in the detail controller.

Comment: This is pretty much done now thank you!